# How to get the current node's name from a nested node in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline and I am trying to get the NODE_NAME of the nested NODE that I switch to. Example:

```
@Library('git lib that we use')
import org.our_git_lib.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

node("master") {
    stage("Do something") {
        // do something on master
    }

    // switch to new node to do some stuff
    node("new_node_label") {
        stage("do something") {
            echo env.NODE_NAME // This echos master NOT the new_node_label name
        }

        stage("do something") {
            // do something in new_node
        }
    }
}
```

The NODE_NAME environment variable is not updated to the new_node_label's node name. How do I get the current node name of the node that is running. In my console output, I do see

```
Running on nested_node_name in /var/jenkins
```

Where the name is being displayed, but I can't actually get that new nested_node_name in a variable. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `echo NODE_NAME`

Comment: @zett42 that still echos master unfortunately

Comment: Just tested your code and it works for me. Test environment is a bit contrived though, because both nodes are running on localhost. Could try to test with a VM for 2nd node tomorrow.

Comment: @zett42 maybe its because before my pipeline starts I import libraries?

Comment: When I echo NODE_NAME or env.NODE_NAME it is always master

Comment: What kind of libs? Can you add the imports to your code sample?

Comment: @zett42 added. I dont think that is it though

Comment: Me too thinks this is not the root cause, unless the libs redefine `node` to something else. Still you could remove the libs to rule this out.

Comment: Yea not issue it seems. Also I did `sh "printenv"` and it printed the correct NODE_LABELS for the new_node_name but did not update the NODE_NAME